# List of Image C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image, list, var

Is there an other way to declare a list of image than using var ?

```
var myimagelist = new Image[9];
```

Because using var I can't declare it in my public class like :

```
private int IndexComp;
var __I_ImageCouche = new Image[9];
```

I'm new at coding, it may be very simple but I couldn't find an answer to my question.

Comment: Try `Image[] myImageList = new Image[9];` That creates an array of `Image`, if you want a list you can do `List<Image> myImageList = new List<Image>()` and you do not need to define the size for `List`.

Comment: You're creating a **variable**. You're looking for a class-level **field** declaration. What @Haldo said is a field declaration. You can also prefix that with an accessibility modifier. The default is `private`, the max one is whatever that class' access level is. The max is `public`

Comment: Oh, I thought have tried this... That was very simple as expected.. Thank you

Comment: Besides all that, there shouldn't be any need to have a list of Image elements at all. Image is a UI element and for displaying collections of images, you should use an ItemsControl where an Image element is declared in the ItemTemplate. You would then assign or bind the ItemsControl's ItemsSource property to a collection of ImageSource objects, or to a collection of image URL strings.

Comment: Read Clemens advice!  With wpf when you see a repeated bunch of anything think in terms of templating data into ui and some sort of itemscontrol.

Comment: How can I change dynamically the size of the List with Clemens' advice ?

Comment: See e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18336535/1136211) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44460018/1136211) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40024424/1136211) post. There are many more. Search the web for ItemsControl and Image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Image[] myimagelist = new Image[9];
```

But I suggest you use

```
List<Image> myImageList = new List<Image>();
```

Comment: Some info: `List` allows adding and removing items dynamically while an array is a fixed amount of items and you can assign to each by index. You can resize an array but `List` already does all that for you and handles all the mess. Depending on your usage, an array may be enough because it's minimal; but you probably need a `List`. It won't matter that much though.